# What will happen on creating a transaction with negative amount?

Tags: transactions, majority-attack, validation, smartcontracts, block-validity

Bitcoin in short is a public ledger guided by consensus of its nodes.

In theory, if there is no validation of transaction amount, if we were to create a transaction with negative amount, that would just do a reverse transaction without the other party's consent.

I might be highly wrong here as validation does take place in such a network. Can someone guide me why something like this can't be done in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every (full) node in the network verifies all rules. Negative transaction amounts are not valid. If a transaction would contain such a transfer, the transaction would be invalid and ignored by the network. If such a transaction would be contained in a block, nodes would ignore the block, and any block that builds on top, resulting in lost effort for the miner that created it.

> In theory, if there is no validation of transaction amount, if we were to create a transaction with negative amount, that would just do reverse transaction without the other party's consent.

Thankfully, everything is validated.